# Why does this li:last-child not work?

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

My CSS rule:

```
#menu-right li:last-child a, #menu-left li:last-child a, #menu-bottom li:last-child a, {
    border: none;
}
```

stopped working after some changes, can anyone tell me why? The testwebsite is [removed]

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to find the element you're talking about on that page.  Can you create an example using http://jsfiddle.net? (no JS required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your rule. There should not be a `,` (comma) before the `{`:

Replace:

```
#menu-bottom li:last-child a, {
```

With:

```
#menu-bottom li:last-child a {
```

Also note that, `:last-child` selector doesn't work with Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8!

Comment: The `:last-child` pseudoclass still cannot be reliably used across browsers. In particular, Internet Explorer versions < 9, and Safari < 3.2 definitely [don't support it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/:last-child#Browser_compatibility), although Internet Explorer 7 and Safari 3.2  *do* support `:first-child`, curiously.

Comment: Arrrgh. Thank you! I'll switch to first-child then.

Comment: Had the same issue buddy, finally changed all to `first-child`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `#menu-bottom li:last-child a, {` with `#menu-bottom li:last-child a {`. You have a comma in your rule which is breaking it.